# Storing text in a char matrix in C

Tags: c, string, memory, dynamic, matrix

I want to take a text from the standard input and store it into an array of strings. But I want the array of strings to be dynamic in memory. My code right now is the following:

```
char** readStandard()
{
  int size = 0;
  char** textMatrix = (char**)malloc(size);
  int index = 0;
  char* currentString = (char*)malloc(10); //10 is the maximum char per string
  while(fgets(currentString, 10, stdin) > 0)
    {
      size += 10;
      textMatrix = (char**)realloc(textMatrix, size);
      textMatrix[index] = currentString;
      index++;
    }
  return textMatrix;
}
```

The result I have while printing is the last string read in all positions of the array.

Example
Reading:
    hello
    nice
    to
    meet
    you

Printing:
    you
    you
    you
    you
    you

Why? I've searched over the Internet. But I didn't find this kind of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are storing the same address (`currentString`) over and over. Try something like

```
while(fgets(currentString, 10, stdin) > 0)
{
     textMatrix[index] = strdup(currentString); /* Make copy, assign that. */
}
```

The function `strdup` is not standard (just widely available). It should be easy to implement it yourself with `malloc` + `memcpy`.

Comment: Why this doesn't work?`char** readStandard()
{
  int size = 0;
  char** textMatrix = (char**)malloc(size);
  int index = 0;
  while(fgets(textMatrix[index], 10, stdin) > 0)
    {
      size += 10;
      textMatrix = (char**)realloc(textMatrix, size);
      index++;
    }
  return textMatrix;
}`

Comment: @EinsteinNatrium That doesn't work since you didn't allocate memory for `textMatrix[index]`.

Comment: Problem solved. I decided to use `textMatrix[index] = malloc(10)` in each iteration. And then, `strcpy(textMatrix[index],currentString)`. Maybe it isn't elegant. But I prefer to avoid the use of `strdup`. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

`currentString` always point to the same memory area and all the pointers in `textMatrix` will point to it

```
char** readStandard()
{
  int size = 0;
  char** textMatrix = (char**)malloc(size);
  int index = 0;
  char currentString[10];
  while(fgets(currentString, 10, stdin) > 0)
    {
      size += sizeof(char*);
      textMatrix = (char**)realloc(textMatrix, size);
      textMatrix[index] = strdup(currentString);
      index++;
    }
  return textMatrix;
}
```